# Are there non-rhotic English speakers who distinguish between [ən] and syllabic [n]?

Tags: english, phonetics

I'm aware that [ən] can be reduced to [n̩] in some circumstances.

Does this possibility also apply to [ən] that comes from former [ɚn] in non-rhotic English dialects? I have had limited contact with non-rhotic English (mostly television), but I only recall hearing *eastern* as [ˈiːstən] rather than [ˈiːsʔn̩] <sup>1</sup>, while words like *prison* are commonly heard with either [ən] or [n̩].

The only information I could find was [these blog comments](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com.br/2009/11/heavnly-scansion.html):

> army198727: Is there anyone who consistently distinguishes /ˈsev.n/
>   "seven" from /ˈsev.ən/ "Severn"? Or is the transcription of the former
>   as /ˈsevn/ in most dictionaries another example of a distinction
>   without a distinction?
>
> mallamb27: Yes I do, and /ˈbɪtn/ 'bitten' from /ˈbɪtən/ 'bittern', /ˈpætn/
>   'patten', 'paten' from /ˈpætən/ 'pattern'. You may find this hard to
>   believe, but I am always banging on about the upper limit of
>   distinctive realization, and this is what makes this distinction
>   justifiable. But only for a probably quite restricted population of
>   consistent speakers. [...]

Do we need to add a new phoneme to the list of English phonemes (as shown by the minimal pairs *bitten*-*bittern*, *pattern*-*patten*, *seven*-*Severn*)? Or is it just an occasional idiosyncratic or artificial distinction?

1. Maybe the former is used in non-TV registers? Maybe I haven't paid enough attention?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think we should take the report of contrast at face value. The consequences of that fact are not obvious, though. Before leaping to a conclusion, you have to set out your analytic axioms, the most relevant issue being what definition of "phoneme" you are operating with. The most widespread understanding of "phoneme" is that a sound is a phoneme if it cannot always be derives from something else, for example [ɾ] in American English can always derive from /t/ or /d/ – whereas, [ʃ] *is* a phoneme because it can't always be derived from /s/ (wash, shore) even though it sometimes can (face, facial).

Assuming that view of phoneme, the primary question would be, are *m̩ n̩ l̩* phonemes of English? There are decent reasons to believe that the syllabic sonorants derive from schwa plus sonorant, especially when a full vowel alternates with schwa owing to paradigmatic stress shifts. See for example *calorie ~ caloric* where the first syllable alternates between stressed [ˈkæl] and unstressed [kl̩]. However, one can plausible derive many instances of syllabic sonorant from an otherwise unsyllabifiable CC cluster, thus /bɒtl/ "bottle", /rɒtn/ "rotten" are possible analyses.

Since there is reportedly no difference between "Peter" and "pita", there would be no reason to posit underlying /r/ in one word and not the other. So if "bitten" comes from /bɪtən/, then what would [bɪtən] "bittern" come from? Perhaps /bɪtərn/, since even though we don't have a reason to posit /r/ in "Peter", we sort of do in "bittern" (it helps us maintain a smaller phoneme inventory). But another analysis is at hand: "bottle" is /bɔtl/, "cotton" is /kɒtn/, and in this dielect there is no reduction of schwa plus sonorant in that dialect – schwa is entirely gone. No new phoneme is added (schwa is already a phoneme); what is "added" is a kind of consonant cluster that wasn't there earlier.

IMO the answer really hangs on the strength of evidence for reduction of /ən/ to [n̩] in that dialect, in particular, the evidence that there is an underlying vowel before the nasal. I suspect that my alternation "canon" [ˈkænən] ~ "canonical" [kn̩̩ˈnɑnɪkl̩] is not found in that dialect of English and instead you have schwa in the first (unstressed) syllable.